# Color inversion using ArrayPlot

Tags: plotting

I have a 3D data that I want to visualise its each slice with ArrayPlot. However, there is a problem the way it represents the data. As,

> ArrayPlot by default generates grayscale output, in which zero values are shown white, and the maximum positive or negative value is shown black.

It conflicts with the general idea, cause it should represent 0 values as black, max value(if it is scaled, equals to 1) as white and the rest of the values as gray levels.

I am playing with it and I wrote a code sample:

```
ArrayPlot[data, ColorFunctionScaling -> True, ColorRules -> {1 -> White, 0 -> Black}]
```

I am not sure whether it is correct. Actually, I am not satisfied with the result.

Any help is appreciated.Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set [`ColorFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ColorFunction.html). Please compare the resulting graphics

```
data = Table[x, {200}, {x, 0, 1, 1/199.}];
ArrayPlot[data]
ArrayPlot[data, ColorFunction -> GrayLevel]
```

### A word to your comment

Using strings as option value to `ColorFunction` lets you easily select one of the [color gradients](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/ColorSchemes.html) provided by *Mathematica*. In all other cases `ColorFunction` should really be a function, meaning that it takes a numeric value and results in a color like `RGBColor`, `GrayLevel`, `Hue`, `CMYKColor` or named colors like `Red` or even `Opacity` combinations.$^1$

Therefore, while `"GrayTones"` is *color gradient*, `GrayLevel` is a function. I hope this clears the confusion.
To add some more confusion, there is a `"Grayscale"` too which is used in `Image` or `Rasterize` to set the `ColorSpace`. Just in case you stumble over it and wonder what's this all about.

$^1$ Actually, you can also return numeric values which are interpreted as colors:

- a triple `{r,g,b}` is interpreted as a rgb-color
- a number is interpreted as a gray level
- a tuple `{g,alpha}` is interpreted as gray level with alpha channel
- a list `{c,m,y,k}` is interpreted as CMYK-color

Comment: Thanks. I had tried this command with quotation marks which didn't make difference(i.e."GrayLevel") :( . By the way, I have just noticed that assigning ColorFunction to "GrayTones" gives the same result.

Comment: @cesm I cleared the confusion why `"GrayLevel`" is not working by adding some information to my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the clearence. Here comes another confusion. I have also used `Image` for visualizing. However, although I assigned `ColorSpace` to Graylevel(or Grayscale), I got a binary image(evidenced by the  histogram). After, I used `ImageAdjust`, I got gray-scale images as I got with `ArrayPlot`. Here is the code that I wrote `Map[ImageAdjust[#] &, 
 Image[data[[;; , ;; , #]], ColorSpace -> "Graylevel"] & /@ 
  Range[1, Dimensions[data][[3]]], {1}]`.